# how to remove the array index from the json output

Tags: php, json

I have the following webservice in php

```
<?php    
if(isset($_GET['user']))
    $idActeur = ($_GET['user']);
$pdo = PdoGsb::getPdoGsb();
$tabVisites = $pdo->getLesVisites($idActeur);
echo json_encode(array('visite'=>$tabVisites));    
?>
```

this webservice returns json of this format

```
[{"id":"5","0":"5","dateVisite":"2015-12-31","1":"2015-12-31","estVisiteProgramme":"1","2":"1","heureArriveeCabinet":"23h58","3":"23h58","heureDebutEntretien":"23h59","4":"23h59","heureDepartCabinet":"23h59","5":"23h59","idMedecin":"3","6":"3","idActeur":"a17","7":"a17"},
```

When doing a var_dump of the variable that is outputed in json I get this

```
array (size=6)
  0 => 
    array (size=16)
      'id' => string '5' (length=1)
      0 => string '5' (length=1)
      'dateVisite' => string '2015-12-31' (length=10)
      1 => string '2015-12-31' (length=10)
      'estVisiteProgramme' => string '1' (length=1)
      2 => string '1' (length=1)
      'heureArriveeCabinet' => string '23h58' (length=5)
      3 => string '23h58' (length=5)
      'heureDebutEntretien' => string '23h59' (length=5)
      4 => string '23h59' (length=5)
      'heureDepartCabinet' => string '23h59' (length=5)
      5 => string '23h59' (length=5)
      'idMedecin' => string '3' (length=1)
      6 => string '3' (length=1)
      'idActeur' => string 'a17' (length=3)
      7 => string 'a17' (length=3)
```

how should I rework my webservice so that the outputed json does not include the array indexes ?

the goal is to have a json that looks like this:

```
[{"id":"5",
"dateVisite":"2015-12-31",
"estVisiteProgramme":"1 }]
```

Here is the method that fetch the results from the database:

```
public function getLesVisites($idActeur)
    {
        // Création requête
        $req = "SELECT * FROM visite WHERE visite.idActeur = '$idActeur'";
        // Exécution de la requête
        $res = PdoGsb::$monPdo->query($req);
        // Stockage de la requête dans la variable $lesVisites
        $lesVisites = $res->fetchAll();
        // Retourne les visites
        return $lesVisites;
    }
```

Comment: Set the `PDO::FETCH_MODE` to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. The default is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which is what you're getting.

Comment: Where should I do that ?

Comment: You can call `$pdo->setAttrValue()` to change the fetch mode right after making the database connection (I assume in your `PdoGsb` class), or you can supply a fetch mode as an argument whenever you call `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` on a PDO result.

Comment: when I switched to fetchAll to fetch_assoc it threw me an error was it what you recommended ?

Comment: No, don't change the function, add an argument. So instead of calling `$result->fetchAll()`, call `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`. See [the manual](https://secure.php.net/pdostatement_fetchall) for more info

Comment: @rickdenhaan answer the question

Comment: @Edward done. Zatharan, could you accept the answer so this question will not linger in the "unanswered" category?

Comment: No problem, I'll be glad to do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `PDO::FETCH_MODE` to `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`. The default is `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`, which is what you're getting. You can call `$pdo->setAttrValue()` to change the fetch mode right after making the database connection (I assume in your `PdoGsb` class), or you can supply a fetch mode as an argument whenever you call `fetch()` or `fetchAll()` on a PDO result, e.g. `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.